# Can't start Elasticsearch on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: elasticsearch

Can't start Elasticsearch v.2.3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

[image]

Comment: ok can you please check the status by typing "sudo service elasticsearch status"

Comment: If it is not working please open /etc/elasticsearch and open elasticsearch.yml file then change  network.host to  network.host: 0.0.0.0 and restart the elasticsearch.It will work

Comment: thanks for quick response @KARTHEEKGUMMALURI. changed network.host to 0.0.0.0. not helped, the same output.

Comment: Which type do you installed like deb file or tar file?

Comment: installed from repo, with apt-get install.

Comment: ok before installation you need to install dependencies like java with latest version.Have you installed that

Comment: sure. used this source - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-production-elasticsearch-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Ok actually debian version is easy to install and in that blog he mentioned to install debian right but you have used repo

Comment: yep, i skip this instruction about installation. installed using repo.

Comment: Ok what you can do is re-install the elasticsearch using deb file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120196/discussion-between-ericpro-and-kartheek-gummaluri).